# Facebook FQL Javascript see if friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I cannot seem to figure this thing out i got everything i wanted working but i cannot get this to work:
I want to see if the active loged in user is friends with a specific account and if they are not the user is promt with a add friend window.
this is what is got:

```
FB.api(
 {
  method: 'fql.query',
  query: 'SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND uid2 = 100001314420757'
 },
 function(response) {
  document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML='Users are: ' + response[0].[something here];
 }
);
```

i think i got the right FQL query (got it from FB) but i need the right response so if you have a name query you'll have response[0].name if tryed about anything i can think of (response.friend or friends and much more but i cannot get it to work.) if i just do response; then i get undefined.

Comment: Do `console.log(response)` in the callback function to see what response you’re _actually_ getting from the API (and look into your browser’s JS console afterwards).

Comment: i added console.log('Friendlog ' + response); and all i get in the console is Friendlog (with no response after it)

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I see with your code is that if the user's aren't friends, the `response` is null. You'll need to test for this.

You can try something like this:

```
  var friendID = '100001314420757';
  FB.api( 
    { 
        method: 'fql.query', 
        query: 'SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND uid2 = '+friendID
     }, 
    function(response) {
        if (response[0] == null || response[0].uid2 != friendID) { 
          alert('You are not friends');
        } else { 
           alert('You are friends.');
        } 
    } 
  );
```